# How to remove database priviliges from inactive database users?

Tags: python, sql, database, griddb

As a database administrator in a company, I need to manage the users of am employees database. I would like to revoke database access rights from every user that has been logged in to the database at least 2 years ago. This is indicated by a column which could either have a value of 0 or a valid year.
The value of 0 indicates that the user is still working actively in the company However, employees (users) who have been fired, or who have left the company have the value has something like 2020 (to indicate that the user left in 2020).

```py
'''
id | user | year_joined | year_left
----+---------+-------------+--------------
0 | user_01 | 2015 | 0 
1 | user_02 | 2013 | 2021
2 | user_03 | 2012 | 2022 
3 | user_04 | 2017 | 2020 
4 | user_05 | 2015 | 0 
5 | user_06 | 2013 | 0 
6 | user_07 | 2016 | 0 
'''
```

I am using GridDB in Python, and the documentation says I could use REVOKE, but how do I use the clause with the conditions I stated above?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you need to get the list of users satisfying the condition. concatenate each list value into text with the revork command. in a loop to send the made lines to send for execution. example : ''revork user_02"   ''revork user_03"   ''revork user_04"